# Strange issue with wordpress - critical error but nothing in debug.log

Tags: wordpress

I have just put some changes to a wordpress theme live, it all works on the staging server but for some reason it's giving a critical error on the live site.

As normal i go and look at the debug.log file and there is no fatal error is showing in that file, and no error_log is showing it either.

Any ideas on why it's not recording the fatal error (usually that is what causes the wordpress critical error)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the "fatal error" you're talking about occurred before WordPress was initialized. For example, if the code, that triggers the error is located in `index.php` of your active theme.

In this case, try to find error messages not in `wp-content/debug.log`, but in webserver logs folder `/var/log/httpd/error_log/` or `/var/log/apache2/error.log`